# Find vectors and a scalar that disprove that $A=\{p(x)\in V:p(0)-p(2)=2\}$ is a subspace of $V=R_3[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

So I am supposed to disprove that $A=\{p(x)\in V:p(0)-p(2)=2\}$ is a subspace of $V=R_3[x]$ by finding $v_1$, $v_2$, and $\alpha$ such that $v_1+\alpha v_2\notin A$. I am honestly kind of stumped here. So far, I have tried to play around with exponents and have found that $x^2-3x+2$ could work as $p$, however I don't think that I am even in the correct direction.

I don't think that I correctly understand the problem and can't seem to find any similar examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $p(x) = -x$.

We have $p(0) - p(2) = 0-(-2) = 2$ so $p \in A$.

However, $2p \notin A$ because $2p(0) - 2p(2) = 0 - 2 \cdot (-2) = 4 \ne 2$.

So, $A$ is not closed under scalar multiplication hence it is not a subspace.

---

A shorter argument:

Every subspace has to contain $0$. However, $0 \notin A$ so $A$ cannot be a subspace.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but I still don't know what vectors $v_1, v_2$ are...

Comment: @CluelessButCurious If you really want to do it that way, you can take $v_1(x) = -x + 1$, $v_2(x) = -x + 2$, and $\alpha = 2$. We have $v_1, v_2 \in A$, but $v_1 + \alpha v_2 \notin A$:
$$-x+1 + 2(-x + 2) = -x + 1 - 2x + 4 = -3x + 5$$
$$(-3\cdot 0 + 5) - (-3 \cdot 2 + 5) = 5 + 6 - 5 = 6 \ne 2$$

Answer (score 2):

$0 \notin A$. So, just take any $v_1 \in A$ and $\alpha=-1$ and $v_2=v_1$.